# Actionscript 3: Textfield Variables

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, text, textfield

I have having a little trouble with my project. I have a textfield which I have given the instance name of money. For the coding, I have this:

```
var money:int = 10;
money.text = "$" + money;
```

I want the variable `money` to be `10`. For the text output, I want it to show `$10`. This isn't working though. I keep getting the error:

```
1151: A con flict exists with definition money in namespace internal.
Source: var money:int = 10;
```

Can you please help me figure out what it is I did wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable and a textfield with the same name.. change the textfield's name.